# How can I access code from linked list into my queue

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

for function addproduct in queue, how can I access the Node * head from the list, so I can add all the item from the linked list into my queue, any help given will be much appreciated thank you. Like in class linkedlist i can access all the pointer use in class Node, but why can't i access the head in linkedlist in the queue.

```
class List;


class Node{
int data;
string food_name;
int price;
int quantity;

public:
Node* next;

//initialization list
//assignment operator
//constructor
Node(int d,string f_name, int p, int q){
    this->data = d;
    this->food_name = f_name;
    this->price = p;
    this->quantity = q;
    this->next = NULL;
}


//to access the private member in the Node
friend class List;
friend class Queue;
};

class List{
Node * head;
Node * tail;

public:

//empty constructor
List():head(NULL),tail(NULL){}

Node* begin(){
    return head;
}

void push_front(int data, string food_name, float price, int quantity){
    if(head==NULL){
        Node*n= new Node(data,food_name, price, quantity);
        head = tail = n;
    }
    else{
        Node*n = new Node(data,food_name, price, quantity);
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }
}

void push_back(int data, string food_name, float price, int quantity){
    if(head==NULL){
        Node*n= new Node(data,food_name, price, quantity);
        head = tail = n;
    }
    else{
        Node*n = new Node(data,food_name, price, quantity);
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}

void insert(int data, string food_name, float price, int quantity, int pos){
    //pos = position
    if(pos==0){
        push_front(data,food_name, price, quantity);
        return;
    }

    //otherwise
    Node* temp = head;
    for(int jump=1; jump<=pos-1;jump++){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    Node *n = new Node(data,food_name, price, quantity);
    n->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = n;
}

}
friend class Queue;
};

class Queue{
public:
    Node * front;
    Node * rear;

    Queue(){
        front = NULL;
        rear = NULL;
    }

    bool isEmpty(){
        if(front==NULL && rear==NULL){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool checkProductExist(int choice){
        Node *temp = front;
        bool exist = false;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            if(temp->data == choice){
                exist=true;
                break;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        return exist;
    }

    //enqueue
    void addproduct (int choice{
        Node *n = head;
        while(n->data != choice){
            n=n->next;
        }

        if(isEmpty()){
            front = n;
            rear = n;
            cout<<"Node Enqueue successfully"<<endl;}
        else{
            if(checkProductExist(choice)== true){
                Node * temp = front;
                while(temp->data!=choice){
                    temp=temp->next;
                }
                temp->quantity+=1;
                cout<<"Quantity +1"<<endl;
            }
            else{
                rear->next = n;
                rear = n;
                //top =n;
                rear->next=NULL;
                cout<<"Node Enqueue successfully"<<endl;
            }

        }

    }
    friend class List;
};
```

Comment: After glancing this over, a rough estimate suggests that at least 95% of the shown code can't possibly have anything to do with the question that's asked; it is only clutter, and obscures whatever the real issue might be. Deleting everything that's completely irrelevant to what's being asked (while still meeting all requirements for a [mre] as explained in the [help]), making it as easy as possible for everyone else to understand your question, is the best way for you to improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Head of which `List` do you want to access? There's no any `List` neither  in Queue class, nor globally, nor in `addproduct` function;

Comment: should i add a parameter to pass List into the addproduct function ?

Comment: I think it would be good to make a pop function for the linked list. That way, you can pop an item from the list and then enqueue it in the queue(granted you have a enqueue function). The next item in the list will be the new head of the list